# iterar sobre una conexion hacia mysql y ejecutar una query

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs

me encuentro con el siguiente problema..

Genero una conexión hacia mysql a traves del siguiente [paquete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#), donde tengo dos tablas: 'rto' y 'vta'. Y en base a eso arme un INNER JOIN donde muestro lo requerido, ahora necesito ejecutar esa query a traves de cada registro de mi tabla rto.

el codigo es el siguiente:

```
//mysql
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'excel'
});

//test conection
connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Connected!\n');
});

//count of remitos
var numrtos;
var gcrtoqy = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rto;';
connection.query(gcrtoqy, (err, cb) => {
  if(err) throw err;
  numrtos = cb[0];
  numrtos = Object.values(numrtos)[0]
  console.log('CANT Remitos:', numrtos);
});

//
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log('\nData:\n');
  for (let i = 1; i <= numrtos; i++) {
    var fullqy = 'SELECT r.fecha, r.importe, v.fecha, v.importe FROM vta v INNER JOIN rto r ON r.id = '+i+' WHERE v.fecha >= r.fecha AND v.importe = r.importe LIMIT 1;';
    connection.query(fullqy, (err,match) => {
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log(match);
    });
  }
}, 500);
```

Lo que recibo es

```
Connected!

CANT Remitos: 3
CANT Ventas: 5

Data:

[ RowDataPacket { fecha: 2016-01-01T03:00:00.000Z, importe: 99 } ]
[ RowDataPacket { fecha: 2016-01-01T03:00:00.000Z, importe: 99 } ]
[ RowDataPacket { fecha: 2016-01-01T03:00:00.000Z, importe: 99 } ]
```

Si bien se realiza bien la cantidad de peticiones solo me muestra el resultado de la ultima, ya que 'i' siempre tiene como valor 3.

La pregunta seria, ¿Como armo el bucle de forma asíncrona para que se ejecuten independientemente cada query que pasa por el bucle?

P.D: No necesito aplicar performance en el codigo. Solo es para generar un reporte unico.

---

Otra alternativa que encuentro es hacer un insert con el resultado de la consulta en mysql

La consulta es la siguiente:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ROWPERROW;
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE PROCEDURE ROWPERROW()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rto INTO n;
SET i=1;
WHILE i<=n DO 


 INSERT INTO rtoxvta (fecharto, importerto, fechavta, importevta)
  SELECT r.fecha, r.importe, v.fecha, v.importe
    FROM vta v 
    left outer join rto r 
    ON r.id = i
    WHERE v.fecha >= r.fecha AND v.importe = r.importe 
    LIMIT 1;
  SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
End;
;;

CALL ROWPERROW();
```

pero ahora el problema es la validación porque necesito hacer coincidir el campo 'importe' entre dos tablas con un margen de error de 2, y en mysql no es posible .**.o si?**